Python function recursion used with try/except error
def main():

    def numSys(x):
        if x == 1:
            print ("BASELINE (1) REACHED!")
            return 1
        else:
            return x * numSys(x-1)

    def userSystem():
        a = input("Initial Number: ")
        try:
            a = int(a)
        except:
            print ("ERROR! Please type a valid number!")
            userSystem()
        
        factorialSum = numSys(a)
        print (factorialSum)
    
    #INITIATE FUNCTIONS
    userSystem()

main()

When inputting a number on the first prompt, it would be successful, but when I test the try/except function by putting a letter first, then putting a number, it would be successful but with a error in the end.
Console log:


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think the reason might be because you're calling userSystem() recursively but you aren't returning the value a from the recursed calling of userSystem() and therefore,  when it finally goes to factorialSum = numSys(a),  I think it uses the old a value (i.e. "a")

Even though you've "handled"  your userSystem wrong input, it still returns to the function to complete what ever is after the try except. you could try returning the userSystem in the except call for a start

Why are you putting a space after print?

@Sayse thank you for the solution, it is now working after I put return userSystem() at the end of the except block.

The problem is (as "Sayse" mentioned) that you're missing a return after you handle the exception.
def numSys(x):
    if x == 1:
        print ("BASELINE (1) REACHED!")
        return 1
    else:
        return x * numSys(x-1)

def userSystem():
    a = input("Initial Number: ")
    try:
        a = int(a)
    except:
        print ("ERROR! Please type a valid number!")
        # add return to exit the current call of the function - to try again
        # otherwise after finishing the second call of the function, the program will
        # still attempt to call numSys on the bad input - and fail
        return userSystem() 
    
    factorialSum = numSys(a)
    print (factorialSum)

def main():
    #INITIATE FUNCTIONS
    userSystem()

main()


There is no need to nest the functions, follow the happy path - once your received a valid integer start the calculation:
def userSystem():
    while 1:
        a = input("Initial Number: ")
        try:
            a = int(a)
            return a
        except:
            print ("ERROR! Please type a valid number!")

def numSys(x):
    if x == 1:
        print ("BASELINE (1) REACHED!")
        return 1
    else:
        return x * numSys(x-1)

def main():
    x = userSystem()
    print(f"Using: {x}")
    print(numSys(x))

main()

Out:
Initial Number: ad
ERROR! Please type a valid number!
Initial Number: ad
ERROR! Please type a valid number!
Initial Number: 3
Using: 3
BASELINE (1) REACHED!
6

